# Why can't we call Standard Query Operators on a sequence of type IQueryable<T>?

Tags: linq

Standard Query Operators operate on Linq to Object sequences, which implement `IEnumerable<T>` interface, while Linq to Sql operators are called on sequences of type `IQueryable<T>` interface. Thus Standard Query Operators cannot get called on a sequence of type `IQueryable<T>` unless this sequence is first cast to `IEnumerable<T>` ( via `AsEnumerable` operator )

a) Why can't Standard Query Operators that don't have Linq to Sql counterparts ( like `Reverse()` ),  be called on a `IQueryable<T>` sequence? Namely, `IQueryable<T>` derives from `IEnumerable<T>` and thus an extension method which extends classes implementing `IEnumerable<T>` should also extend classes implementing interfaces derived from `IEnumerable<T>`  ?!

b) Anyways, why would it be a bad idea to be able to call Standard Query Operators ( those that don't have Linq to Sql counterparts ) on a sequence of type `IQueryable<T>`, without first casting this sequence to `IEnumerable<T>` ( via `AsEnumerable` operator )?

thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IQueryable<T>` in general is not just for Linq to SQL, it's a convention that any query provider may choose to support with a limited set of operations - not all query providers support the same subset.

The subset that is supported depends on what makes sense in the domain of the query provider. `IQueryable<T>` operates on an expression tree that allows the query provider to translate the query into a domain specific language for the underlying data source (i.e. SQL).

Comment: I remember being asked something similar to this not so long ago.  BrokenGlass has it pretty bang-on.  Consider IQueryable<T> as an expression, a function or list of functions as it were.  IEnumerable is in-memory results - whether they were derived from IQueryable or otherwise.  Once you understand this, you'll see why IEnumerable's functions won't work on IQueryable.  +1 to BrokenGlass

Comment: I must confess that I know nothing about expression trees. Anyways, from the C# syntax rules point of view, calling IQueryable<T>.Reverse should work, as explained in my initial post. I'm curious why C# rules don't apply here?

Comment: @flockofcode: they do apply - this will not create a *compile time error* (since the extension method is defined for `IQuerable<T>` but a *run time error* if is not supported (i.e. if there is no equivalent in the domain that the query provider is mapping to) by the particular query provider you are using. For Linq to SQL i.e. you will get an exception when trying to use TakeWhile, SkipWhile, Reverse, Last, LastOrDefault, etc. - complete list at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399342.aspx

Comment: Book I'm reading claimed: "there is no Reverse method for IQueryable<T> interface, so the exception was thrown.", which doesn't make sense, since if Reverse wasn't defined for IQueryable<T>, then we should be able to call Linq to Object's Reverse on IQueryable<T> sequence. Anyways, thank you both for your help

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your question Linq to SQL query produces the SQL query because linq to SQL is different Linq provider,  IEnumerable used for query in memory collections